# How do I properly use polymorphism using component pattern which has circular dependency?

Tags: c++, design-patterns, circular-dependency

I have an `Entity` class:

```
// It includes three components
#include "InputComponent.h"
#include "PhysicsComponent.h"
#include "AnimationComponent.h"
class Entity
{
public:
    // It has three component pointers
    InputComponent* input; 
    PhysicsComponent* physics;
    AnimationComponent* animation; 

    // it also has a virtual function
    virtual void Update(void);
}
```

A component looks like this:

```
class Entity; // Declare class instead of include, to avoid circular dependecy
class InputComponent
{
public:
    virtual void Update(Entity& entity); // The method I want to overide with polymorphism
}
```

for the implementation to work I write `#include "Entity.h"` in the `InputComponent.cpp` file.
I have for example a `PlayerInputComponent` that inherits from `InputComponent` with modified behavior.

```
class Player; // Avoiding circular dependency again
class PlayerInputComponent : public InputComponent
{
public:
    virtual void Update(Player& player); // Player instead of Entity
}
```

This creates a behavior I do not want, hence it the ability to use polymorphism. So when I do the following it won't work properly:

I have a player that inherits from Entity:

```
#include "Entity.h"
class Player : public Entity
{
    virtual void Update(...);
    Player(InputComponent* ic, PhysicsComponent* pc, AnimationComponent* ac);
}
```

and I create a player typing `Player(new PlayerInputComponent(), new PlayerPhysicsComponent(), new PlayerAnimationComponent());` using only extended components for the player.
But with this faulty behavior, the derived components calls their base functions via their basepointer instead of the derived version.

How can I solve this?
Is there a way to fix what I find ugly about the circular dependency in the component pattern?

Comment: You cannot override a function with one of a different signature. Is there something wrong with having `virtual void Update(Entity& player);` in `PlayerInputComponent`?

Comment: Aww really? Because my player class has information that Entity dont, so I cant access everything I want to update through Entity in my extended component class. If I could, I wouldn't have the need to create custom components. Any Ideas?

Comment: Yes, really. Your Entity class and its children should work via virtual functions. Any stuff that Player has and Entity does not, should be manipulated in these functions, and not directly by PlayerComponent or whatever.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
virtual void Update(Player& player); // Player instead of Entity
```

Here you don't override the Update method, because it have a different syntax. If you write this:

```
 virtual void Update(Player& player) override; // Player instead of Entity
```

Probably you will get a compile error.

Give your parameter an Entity* and check in the function with dynamic_cast if it's a player or not. I don't think it will work correctly if you want to pass a derived class ptr in the derived class update function, but you can try it.

Comment: Like this? `virtual void Update(Entity& entity);` and in my implementation: `Player* player = dynamic_cast<Player*>(&entity);`?
You may also explain why I should use `override` keyword! Thanks

Comment: Dynamic cast in business logic is a sign of a faulty design.

Comment: I am aware of that, but I currently don't have the knowledge to redesign my code. Right now I'm breaking it up into small managable chunks so when I open this project up in 6 month, it wont look like complete jibberish. I have also only taken one course in C++, so I have about 2 month experience with this language. Creating a super mario bros clone is challenging as it is, but any suggestions are more than welcome. I want to be the best, and I wont be that with faulty design.

Comment: @Pontus Magnusson: No, `virtual void Update(Entity* entity);`
`Player* player = dynamic_cast<Player*>(entity);
If (player == nullptr)
 return;`
the keyword override will tell the compiler, that it should override something, so when there is no function to override, it give you an error.

@n. m: I work a pretty big company, and i can say: NO. Dynamic cast is a useful thing when you use polymorphism. However reinterpret_cast and const_cast is the sign of bad design.

Comment: First things first, Why do I want to use a pointer instead of a reference on `virtual void Update(Entity? entity);`
We were taught in class that casting is bad, but sometimes necessary, so striving for cast-free alternatives is the best design, since casting very often generates code which isnt good for performance. In my case performance isnt a problem. And I very much like to hear from people who have actual work experience. School overall seem to have a very theoretic and mostly dated view on things.

Comment: @Melcon I think you are getting it slightly wrong. "reinterpret_cast and const_cast is the sign of bad design" — those are signs of terminal incompetence, not of a faulty design. Those are simply wrong tools for the job. Dynamic cast is the right tool for the job, the only problem is that that job in question is patching a faulty design. Not in absolutely every case, but pretty often.

Answer (score 1):

A common way of dealing with this is templatizing the entire class hierarchy:

```
template <typename EntityType,
      typename InputComponentType,
      typename PhysicsComponentType,
      typename AnimationComponentType>
class Entity { ... }; 
// same parameters in InputComponent and all others

class Player : public Entity<Player, 
    PlayerInputComponent, 
    PlayerPhysicsComponent,
    PlayerAnimationComponent> { ... };
// same structure for PlayerInputComponent and all others
```